# Failing to read users using ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles

I am trying to read application-userroles.yml file. But, it seems like my pojo is not able to read the yml files.

```
application.yml

spring:
  profiles:
    active: qa

spring.profiles.include: userroles    

application-qa.yml

server: 
   port: 8090
   servlet:
    context-path: /order-manager 

osm.service:
    #qa url
    nceurl: http://qa:80/OrderManagement/wsapi
    ncwurl: http://qa2:80/OrderManagement/wsapi
    userId: qa
    password: qa123


logging.config: config/logback.xml

application-userroles.yml

osmtest:
  clients:
    - username: tos
      password: tos123
      roles: ADMIN
    - username: tony
      password: tony123
      roles: USER
    - username: sherry
      password: sherry123
      roles: USER


@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "osmtest")
public class ApplicationClients {

    private List<ApplicationClient> clients = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<ApplicationClient> getClients() {
        return clients;
    }

    public void setClients(List<ApplicationClient> clients) {
        this.clients = clients;
    }   
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class ApplicationClient {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String[] roles;
}


@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@ConditionalOnWebApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan("com.spectrum.sci.config")
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApplicationClients.class)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SecurityConfiguration.class);

    private final ApplicationClients applicationClients = new ApplicationClients();

    public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        //httpSecurity.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/*").permitAll();

        httpSecurity.formLogin().permitAll()
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/order/greet").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/order").hasRole("USER")
        .anyRequest().authenticated(); 
    }

    @Bean
    public InMemoryUserDetailsManager inMemoryUserDetailsManager() {
       final InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();

       log.info("Importing {} clients: " , applicationClients.getClients().toString());

       //Test purposes added bp user
       ApplicationClient appClient = new ApplicationClient();
       appClient.setUsername("bp");
       appClient.setPassword("bp");
       String[] roles = {"ADMIN", "USER"}; 
       appClient.setRoles(roles);
       applicationClients.getClients().add(appClient);

       applicationClients.getClients().forEach(client -> {
           manager.createUser(User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                   .username(client.getUsername())
                   .password(client.getPassword())
                   .roles(client.getRoles())
                   .build());
           log.info("Imported Clients {} " , client.getUsername() + "roles = " + client.getRoles().toString());
       });
       return manager;
    }
}
```

I tried to test with bp account which I added in the inMemoryUserDetailsManager method itself and it works. But, it does not read the application-userroles.yml file.  I believe I have added every annotation and also my pom contains spring-boot-configuration-processor artifactId and i have set filtering true for src/main/resources.

Comment: how are you trying to access? Header Basic username:pwd and request might have {"username":..., "password":...}

Comment: I used browser to put http://localhost:8090/order-manager/order/greet  then login page appear which asked me to put userid and password. I added uid as tos & password tos123 but got                                                                                                            [User 'tos' not found]
[2020-03-25 10:23:33.930] [DEBUG] [Context:UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter] [] [Authentication request failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials]
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Bad credentials

Answer (score 0):

I made below changes in SecurityConfiguration class and it worked.

I used

@Autowired
ApplicationClients applicationClients;

instead of

private final ApplicationClients applicationClients = new ApplicationClients();